# Disable javascript's features in chrome & mozilla to simulate beauvoir in older browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I've the following scripts in my website that now i need to adapt to support older browsers. So my question is:

In chrome & mozilla there are way to disable specific features (like fetch api, and so on) to simulate the beauvoir without the need to download old browser?

The expected beauvoir is that, let's say for example that i've disabled the fetchAPI and, then, I run the following command in a script:

```js
console.log('fetch' in window)
```

the console window must return false instead of true (as new browser support the fetchAPI).

Comment: To remove `fetch` from the current window, you can do `delete window.fetch`. Afterwards `console.log('fetch' in window)` returns `false`

Comment: @qrsngky Hi, thank you for answering so fast. If you can post an official answer i'm going to accept it.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure if the same trick works for the other features you may want to disable. And by 'beauvoir', did you mean 'behavior'?

Comment: @qrsngky originally my idea was to disable even the fetch() function (like simulate an older browser into the new ones) but this method works enough with a chrome extension so i can simulate the browsers where the fetchAPI are unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of `fetch`, you can do `delete window.fetch` or even just
`delete fetch`. 
Afterwards, `console.log('fetch' in window)` will return false.

You may need to check if the same trick works for other features you want to disable.